# Laravel - foreach loop returns Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, laravel, foreach, laravel-5.4

I have a collection of arrays (18), that ALL have a relation - `question`.

**Function getting the data:**

```
 $auditResults = Audit::where('audit_id', $id)
     ->with('question', 'question.auditQuestion')
     ->get();
```

Within the question array, I can see the attributes I'd like to access. When I attempt to access it, I get a `Trying to get property of non-object`

**Collection:**

```
Collection {#407 ▼
  #items: array:18 [▼
    0 => Audit {#411 ▶}
    1 => Audit {#412 ▶}
    2 => Audit {#413 ▶}
    ... shortened for brevity's sake
    14 => Audit {#425 ▶}
    15 => Audit {#426 ▶}
    16 => Audit {#427 ▶}
    17 => Audit {#428 ▶}
  ]
}
```

**Output of an`Audit`:**

```
@foreach($auditResults as $answer)
    {{$answer}}
@endforeach
```

---

```
{  
       "id":1,
       "audit_id":1,
       "audit_questions_details_id":2,
       "question":{  
          "id":2,
          "audit_question_id":2,
          "question_number":1,
          "comment":1,
          "header":0,
          "created_at":"2017-03-27 12:16:50",
          "updated_at":"2017-03-27 12:16:50",
          "audit_question":{  
             "id":2,
             "audit_detail_id":1,
             "question":"Lorum Ipsum Dorum",
             "created_at":"2017-03-27 12:16:50",
             "updated_at":"2017-03-27 12:16:50"
          }
       },
       "score":null,
       "comment":null,
       "created_at":null,
       "updated_at":null
    }
```

If I then proceed to access the question relationship:

```
@foreach($auditResults as $answer)
    {{$answer->question}}
@endforeach
```

It outputs only a number (I'm unsure what it actually is!, as I'd expect it to output the question relationship):

```
1
2
3
4
```

Why is this only outputting a number, when it should be outputting the question array itself, as shown above?

The error is shown when I try to access the `question` relation:

```
@foreach($auditResults as $answer)
    {{$answer->question->id}}
@endforeach
```

**Audit Model:**

```
class Audit extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'audit_id', 'audit_questions_details_id', 'question', 'score', 'comment'
    ];

    public function auditScore()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\AuditScore', 'id', 'audit_id');
    }

    public function question(){
        return $this->belongsTo(AuditQuestionDetail::class, 'audit_questions_details_id');
    }

}
```

Data of Audit Model:

[image: AuditModelData]

**AuditQuestionDetail Model:**

```
class AuditQuestionDetail extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'audit_questions_details';

    protected $fillable = [
        'audit_question', 'question_number', 'comment',
    ];

    public function auditQuestion()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(AuditQuestion::class, 'id', 'audit_question_id');
    }

    public function score()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Audit::class);
    }
}
```

[image: AuditQuestionDetails Data]

Many thanks.

Comment: Please show your model `Audit` with relationship `question` and, probably, the model `Question`.

Comment: @AlexanderReznikov - many thanks, I've updated the description.

Comment: Thanks, but I want to see properties of your model class `Audit`. May be you have public class property `question` which replaces the relationship `question`.

Comment: Apologies, I've added a screenshot of the data/schema of each model. I hope that helps.

Comment: I believe @AlexanderReznikov is asking for all of the code in your Audit model, not all of the columns in the database table, since maybe you have some class variable with the name 'question'. But i might be wrong.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm talking about your PHP class for the model `Audit`. May be in this class you have something which replaces `question` relationship. So @user3494047 is right, I want to see whole class for the model `Audit`, may be here we can find the problem.

Comment: @AlexanderReznikov, added full `audit` and `auditQuestionsDetails` model code.

Comment: I see, thanks. You can try to `dd` single member of the collection, for example: `@foreach($auditResults as $answer) <?php dd($answer); ?> ...` and look on the protected property `relation`. Will you see `"question" => AuditQuestionDetail { ...` in this property? Or, even better, please show full dump of the single instance of the model `Audit` from your collection `$auditResults`.

Comment: Yes I can `#observables: []
  #relations: array:1 [▼
    "question" => AuditQuestionDetail {#432 ▶}
  ]
  #touches: []`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure, that I found your problem: you have `question` field in your table for the model `Audit`, so, for some reasons, Laravel prioritises this field above relation with the same name `question`. Just try to rename relationship in your model `Audit`:

For example, change this

```
public function question(){
    return $this->belongsTo(AuditQuestionDetail::class, 'audit_questions_details_id');
}
```

on this:

```
// I know this isn't the best name, just for the test purposes
public function rquestion(){
    return $this->belongsTo(AuditQuestionDetail::class, 'audit_questions_details_id');
}
```

And try:

```
@foreach($auditResults as $answer)
    {{$answer->rquestion}}
@endforeach
```

If you will see in this `foreach` not just the numbers, but JSON of the instances of the model `AuditQuestionDetail`, then you can use any available field from this relationship:

```
@foreach($auditResults as $answer)
    {{$answer->rquestion->id}}
@endforeach
```

Comment: So far so good! It now returns `{"id":2,"audit_question_id":2,"question_number":1,"comment":1,"header":0,"created_at":"2017-03-27 12:16:50","updated_at":"2017-03-27 12:16:50","audit_question":{"id":2,"audit_detail_id":1,"question":"LORUM IPSUM...","created_at":"2017-03-27 12:16:50","updated_at":"2017-03-27 12:16:50"}}` I want to access `audit_question` array, but using `->audit_question` it returns blank.

Comment: Yes, I tested your case (via creation table field and relation with the same name) and my behaviour is the same, so just rename your relationship or your table field.

Comment: rename `audit_question` relationship?

Comment: No, rename method  `public function question` in your class `Audit`. In my example, I renamed `question` into `rquestion` method, so I can get any available field of this relationship via `$answer->rquestion->FIELD`.

Comment: It is now `rquestion`. I can see the information (as shown above) but I can't access it for some reason. Currently using this: `@foreach($auditResults as $result)
                @foreach($result->rquestion as $value)
                {{ $value->id }}
                <hr />
            @endforeach`

Comment: You have `one-to-one` relationship between `Audit` and `AuditQuestionDetail` models, so you don't need second loop via `foreach`. Iif you want to get the `id` attribute from your relationship `rquestion`, just get it like this:  `@foreach($auditResults as $result) {{ $result->rquestion->id }} @endforeach`

Comment: Sorry, if you can see in the output on the first comment, you can see there is a nested array within it called `audit_question`, that's the array I would like to access, not just within `rquestion`. Many thanks.

Comment: If I try and access it like this `@foreach($auditResults as $result)
                {{dd($result->rquestion->audit_question)}}
            @endforeach` it returns `null`. Why would it return `null`?

Comment: I see that you had error here: `{{$answer->question->id}}`, so with the renaming `rquestion` this error should gone.   But about `audit_question`: if you are getting `null` with `$result->rquestion->audit_question)`, then probably this relationship between `AuditQuestionDetail ` and `AuditQuestion` models in this particular case doesn't exist in your DB. Or may be you have another problems with the names of the DB fields/relationship.

Comment: I had to change in AuditQuestionsModel - from `hasOne`, to `belongsTo`. Still, you have been a huge help, and you resolved part of the issue! I appreciate your help. Thank you very much.

Comment: Glad to hear it. I'm ready to help with all your issues about this relationships, if I will know what do you want as the result from these relationships. `Null` usually means in this case, that Laravel couldn't find row from the related table by your relationship rules (names of the fields).

Comment: Thank you once again, you've been a massive help!